# Selmer ranks unbounded?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Is it known if the Selmer ranks of quadratic twist families are unbounded?

Suppose that $E/K$ is an elliptic curve defined over a number field. For each quadratic extension $F/K$ I can form the twist $E^F$ via the character of $F$. Is there a choice of $E/K$ such that the Selmer ranks $\mathrm{rank} \, \mathrm{Sel}_n(E^F)$ are known to be unbounded?

Comment: For $n=2$ yes, see e.g. Thm. 1.4 and 1.9 in https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/10356588/Mazur_RanksTwistsEllip.pdf